# Error installing leaflet package for R in ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu, dependencies, leaflet, install.packages

I can't install the leaflet packages for R in ubuntu. I've correctly install R and I was able to install some other packages like "RCurl" but I cannot install leaflet... Here are the output I get :

```
install.packages("leaflet",dep=T)
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning: dependency ‘plyr’ is not available
also installing the dependencies ‘scales’, ‘rgdal’

trying URL 'http://cran.univ-lyon1.fr/src/contrib/scales_0.3.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 57030 bytes (55 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 55 Kb

trying URL 'http://cran.univ-lyon1.fr/src/contrib/rgdal_1.1-3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1647483 bytes (1.6 Mb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 1.6 Mb

trying URL 'http://cran.univ-lyon1.fr/src/contrib/leaflet_1.0.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 401681 bytes (392 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 392 Kb

ERROR: dependency ‘plyr’ is not available for package ‘scales’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/scales’
* installing *source* package ‘rgdal’ ...
** package ‘rgdal’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
configure: CC: gcc -std=gnu99
configure: CXX: g++
configure: rgdal: 1.1-3
checking for /usr/bin/svnversion... no
configure: svn revision: 594
checking for gdal-config... no
no
configure: error: gdal-config not found or not executable.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgdal’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rgdal’
ERROR: dependency ‘scales’ is not available for package ‘leaflet’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/leaflet’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmp9C0NCQ/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("leaflet", dep = T) :
  installation of package ‘scales’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("leaflet", dep = T) :
  installation of package ‘rgdal’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages("leaflet", dep = T) :
  installation of package ‘leaflet’ had non-zero exit status
```

It looks like this is a dependencies problem but I did try to install it with install.packages("leaflet",dep=T). Do you have a idea ?

Comment: You need to have gdal installed in order to compile this.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/206593/how-to-install-rgdal-on-ubuntu-12-10 for example.